# Floating net labels

Tags: altium

I am learning [Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/altium-designer/) and currently I am getting [Floating Net Labels](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/WorkspaceManager_Err-FloatingNetLabels((Floating+Net+Labels))_AD) warnings/errors (depends on project options) while trying to compile project at following situation:
[image: Floating Net Label warning]
here is selected warning situation:
[image: Selected Warning]
and here is warning itself (there are other I think identical warnings and once the first one will be solved, the others will not be a problem):

```
[Warning]   INPUT_SELECTOR.SchDoc   Compiler    Floating Net Label AUDIO_INPUT_ACTIVE1 at (70,590)
```

Now, I have read the [Floating net labels docs](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/WorkspaceManager_Err-FloatingNetLabels((Floating+Net+Labels))_AD) and:

1. I am connecting [Wire](https://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-Wire((Wire))_AD) to [Bus](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-Bus((Bus))_AD) and **NOT** [Line](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-Line((Line))_AD) to [Bus](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-Bus((Bus))_AD)
2. The [Net Label](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-NetLabel((Net+Label))_AD) **IS** positioned to the [Wire](https://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-Wire((Wire))_AD)

The sheet is part of multisheed design and can someone give me some hints, what could be wrong, since these warnings are very annoying?

Comment: It's usually cause by the net label being not actually attached to the wire. Select the net label, cut it (Ctrl-X) and paste it (Ctrl-V). As you drag it to the wire you should see a red X where it will attach to the wire. Then mouse click to place it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Altium says my labels are floating](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93855/altium-says-my-labels-are-floating)

Comment: "Duplicate" vote retracted - not quite the same issue

Comment: Check your grids. Try to re-attach the net label to the wire. If the grid is off by a hair it will still complain that the label is floating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Texas Instruments ULN2003A IC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf) used here was created automaticaly using [Altium's Eagle Import Wizard](https://www.altium.com/documentation/17.0/display/ADES/((EAGLE+Import))_AD) and something went wrong while importing parts. I've removed created library from project (and deleted part from schematics), downloaded part from [SamacSys](https://componentsearchengine.com/ga/part.php?partID=183032), imported it into project, used part in schematic, recompiled project and warning/errors went away. Since I am newbie at `Altium`, I do not know what exactly went wrong in import proces from Eagle.